# mac mini(2010) can not bootup

Tags: macos, mac, mac-mini

I have an old mac mini (2010 type)
memory has been upgraded to 4M
hard disk 110g used, 2g free left
yesterday when I reboot the mac mini
it always displayed the small circle then shutdown automatically.
I try to press key 'shift' to enter safe mode
[image]

but result is same, it shutdown automatically after 2,3 minutes, there is no logon window display.

I try to press key 'Option' to enter 'disk utility'.

[image]

verifying the disk also failed.

[image]

Your comment welcome

Comment: is it possible to read the data from the disk？

Comment: Unlikely. You may need data recovery services

Comment: You might get better results plugging the drive into a USB enclosure & trying to access it on another machine. Your disk is ***critically*** full & the machine is probably having great difficulty finding enough room to play with when it's running repairs.

Comment: Here's a [guide](https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/Mac+Mini+Mid+2010+Hard+Drive+Replacement/3113) to removing the HD, if you decide to go that route.

Comment: @Tetsujin I also guess the reason is disk full, do you know any converter that can convert hard disk interface to usb?

Comment: @Tetsujin I have got it, please set your comment as answer and I will accept it

Answer (score 0):

From comments...

You might get better results plugging the drive into a USB enclosure & trying to access it on another machine. Your disk is ***critically*** full & the machine is probably having great difficulty finding enough room to play with when it's running repairs.

*based on the OP's* ... "hard disk 110g used, 2g free"

& from MMB's comment -
Here's an [iFixit guide](https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/Mac+Mini+Mid+2010+Hard+Drive+Replacement/3113) to removing the HD, if you decide to go that route.