# how to remove content belong to another mac mini

Tags: macos, mac, mac-mini

I have two mac mini.
One of them has almost full hard disk cause it can not be recoveried automatically.
[mac mini(2010) can not bootup](https://superuser.com/questions/1103419/mac-mini2010-can-not-bootup)

I hope use another new mac mini access the hard disk of this mac mini using sata to usb adapter and remove some useless contents.

When I try to remove the a file in the hard disk belong to the old mac mini, there was alarm widow display said that you can not remove the content in the hard disk.

It looks like the new mac mini has no right to edit the file in the old mac mini.

Your comment welcome

Comment: Try opening the terminal and typing `sudo chmod -R 777 some-path` where some-path is the path to whatever folder you want to copy.  You may need to run this with the Admin account.

Comment: @theJack it still said 'chmod

Comment: Unable to change file mode on some-path

Comment: Try running ` chflags -R nouchg path` first, then run the `chmod`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So long as you are not booted from any given volume, then you can just Get Info on the it & check "Ignore ownership on this volume".

Comment: I unchecked that option, same error

Comment: Then I'd guess the drive has deeper issues. I'd give up on it & recover from backup to a new drive.